Error: NEXT_NOT_FOUND coming when moving to a not present username in /[username] route in NEXT.js
I am building a website using Next.js where users can make their accounts and accepts payments by their followers through the website (much like patreon website).  For each user, I have made a /[username] dynamic route to accept payments. when a username which is not present in database tries to access /[username] page then not-found.js page is not opening instead Error: NEXT_NOT_FOUND is coming.  This is my /[username] page (fetchuser is a server side function which fetches user from database) -
"use client"

import PaymentPage from '@/components/PaymentPage'
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'
import connectDB from '@/db/connectDb'
import User from '@/models/User'
import { fetchuser } from '@/actions/useractions'

const page = ({ params }) => {

    //if username is not present in database, show a 404 error
    useEffect(() => {
        const checkUser = async () => {
            console.log(`in ${params.username}`)
            let u = await fetchuser(params.username)
            console.log(`value of u ${u}`)
            if (u === undefined) {
                try {
                    notFound();
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("error", error)
                }
            }

        }
        checkUser()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <PaymentPage username={params.username} />
        </>
    )

}

export default page

After reading docs i tried to put notFound() function in server side file but it's still showing the same error (Error: NEXT_NOT_FOUND).
I also added not-found.js file in /[username] folder but still same error is coming.
On going through earlier questions on stack overflow, i came across this Next 13.3: How to use NotFound() for a 404 Page but here also no solution was present.
Long story short, i tried everything still it's showing same error again & again. I am comparatively new to next.js framework so pardon me if there are some silly errors.
This is my not-found.js file -
import Link from 'next/link'
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Not Found</h2>
      <p>Could not find requested resource</p>
      <Link href="/">Return Home</Link>
    </div>
  )
} 

image of folder structure

The not-found.js file should be inside the app folder since it is a generic handler for any 404, not just for those in /[username].

I have tried doing that but same error is coming: Error: NEXT_NOT_FOUND

I don't know why it's not detecting not-found.js file.

Could you share your folder structure and what you have inside that not-found.js file?

I have added folder structure at the end of my question just above reactjs and nextjs tags and also added not-found.js file.

You have three different not-found.js files in your tree, are you sure you're editing the correct one?

yes, i am editing the one in app folder and that is the one being displayed above

The way notFound works is by throwing an error ("NEXT_NOT_FOUND").
Here is the source code of notFound :
const NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE = "NEXT_NOT_FOUND";
function notFound() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
    const error = new Error(NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE);
    error.digest = NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE;
    throw error;
}

To make Next handle this error, it needs to be thrown in a component. Here, you are throwing the error asynchronously, so Next can't catch it. You may do it this way (I didn't try it, let me know if this doesn't work, I'll update) :
"use client"

import PaymentPage from '@/components/PaymentPage'
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'
import connectDB from '@/db/connectDb'
import User from '@/models/User'
import { fetchuser } from '@/actions/useractions'

const page = ({ params }) => {
    const [should404, setShould404] = useState(false);

    //if username is not present in database, show a 404 error
    useEffect(() => {
        const checkUser = async () => {
            console.log(`in ${params.username}`)
            let u = await fetchuser(params.username)
            console.log(`value of u ${u}`)
            if (u === undefined) {
                setShould404(true);
            }

        }
        checkUser()
    }, []);

    if (should404) {
        notFound();  // Throw the error in the component, so that Next can handle it
    }

    return (
        <>
            <PaymentPage username={params.username} />
        </>
    )

}

export default page

